# Android: Saving form data on a swipe rather than from a button

Tags: android, android-viewpager, save, swipe, android-tabbed-activity

I am very new to android and this is my second app. I am making a tabbed activity where the first fragment has a form to create a new task, the second fragment has the list of all the saved tasks, and the third fragment will show the comments on a task when selected from the list in the second fragment. When I click on the Save Task button on the first fragment, the app correctly saves the task and shows it in the list of tasks in the next fragment. However, I don't want to use a "Save Task" button in the first fragment. I want to be able to save the task as soon as the user swipes from the first activity to the second.

For this, I have tried calling the fragment's `saveTask()` method from the `OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled()` method in the activity, but all the views in the fragment give a `NullPointerException`. If I try to `performClick()` on the Save Task button from the activity's `OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged()`, even the button gives a `NullPointerException`. When I print to the log to see if the Save Task button has been initialized, the log correctly shows the button ID. I am at a loss as to how to save the task to the database using just a swipe. Please help!

Here is my main activity:

```
public class AddTask extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private static SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
public List<String> fragments = new Vector<String>();

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_task);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //fill the fragments list with the fragment classes
    fragments.add(AddTaskFragment.class.getName());
    fragments.add(TasksFragment.class.getName());
    fragments.add(CommentsFragment.class.getName());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    final AddTaskFragment addTaskFrag = (AddTaskFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    actionBar.setTitle("Add New Task");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    actionBar.setTitle("Existing Tasks");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    actionBar.setTitle("Comments");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (fragments.get(position).equals(TasksFragment.class.getName())) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()==0) {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    if (addTaskFrag != null) {
                        addTaskFrag.saveTaskBtn.performClick();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_task, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "AddTask Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ishita.assigntasks/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "AddTask Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ishita.assigntasks/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public List<String> fragmentsA;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentsA = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Instantiate the fragment at the position where the pager is.
        return Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragmentsA.get(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // return how many fragments there are in the tabbed activity
        return fragmentsA.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Add Task";
            case 1:
                return "Tasks List";
            case 2:
                return "Comments";
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my fragment form Java for creating a new class:

```
/**
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
*/
public class AddTaskFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public String mAssigneeName;
public String mAssigneeContact;
public String mTaskName;
public String mDueDate;
public String mComments = null;

public AddTaskFragment() {
}

EditText dueDate;
EditText assignee;
EditText taskDescription;
EditText comments;
Button saveTaskBtn;
View rootView;
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};

private void updateLabel() {

    String displayFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"; //setting the format in which the date will be displayed
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(displayFormat, Locale.US);

    dueDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static AddTaskFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    AddTaskFragment fragment = new AddTaskFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_task, container, false);

    dueDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.due_date);
    taskDescription = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    comments = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
    assignee = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.assignee);

    dueDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                                               .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                               myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                                   }
                               }

    );

    assignee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    saveTaskBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.save_task);
    Log.v("AddTaskFragment", "saveTaskBtn assigned to " + R.id.save_task);
    saveTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveTask();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public void saveTask(){
    try {
        mTaskName = taskDescription.getText().toString();
        taskDescription.setText("");
        mDueDate = dueDate.getText().toString();
        dueDate.setText("");
        mComments = comments.getText().toString();
        comments.setText("");
        assignee.setText(R.string.assignee_prompt);
        if (mTaskName == null || mDueDate == null || mAssigneeName == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fields cannot be empty. Please fill some values.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            UpdateTask updateDB = new UpdateTask();
            updateDB.execute();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Task saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    EditText assignee = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.assignee);
    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contactData, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    mAssigneeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    mAssigneeContact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    assignee.setText(mAssigneeName);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mAssigneeName + " has number " + mAssigneeContact, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            break;
    }

}

public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ContentValues taskDetails = new ContentValues();
        taskDetails.put(TasksContract.TaskEntry.COL_DESCRIPTION, mTaskName);
        taskDetails.put(TasksContract.TaskEntry.COL_ASSIGNEE_KEY, mAssigneeContact);
        taskDetails.put(TasksContract.TaskEntry.COL_CREATOR_KEY, "creatorID");
        taskDetails.put(TasksContract.TaskEntry.COL_DUE_DATE, mDueDate);
        taskDetails.put(TasksContract.TaskEntry.COL_COMMENTS, mComments);

        getContext().getContentResolver().insert(TasksContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI, taskDetails);

        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(
                TasksContract.ProfileEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{TasksContract.ProfileEntry._ID},
                TasksContract.ProfileEntry.COL_CONTACT + "=?",
                new String[]{mAssigneeContact},
                null
        );
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            ContentValues contactDetails = new ContentValues();
            contactDetails.put(TasksContract.ProfileEntry.COL_NAME, mAssigneeName);
            contactDetails.put(TasksContract.ProfileEntry.COL_CONTACT, mAssigneeContact);

            getContext().getContentResolver().insert(TasksContract.ProfileEntry.CONTENT_URI, contactDetails);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
  }

}
```

And here is the XML for the fragment:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ishita.assigntasks.AddTaskFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/task_prompt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/assignee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/assignee_prompt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/due_date"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/due_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="date" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/comments"
        android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/save_task" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

LogCat:

```
02-18 13:48:05.538 3752-3752/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-18 13:48:05.628 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
02-18 13:48:05.664 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
02-18 13:48:05.664 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
02-18 13:48:05.823 3752-3788/com.example.ishita.assigntasks D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-18 13:48:05.840 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-18 13:48:06.039 3752-3788/com.example.ishita.assigntasks I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                      Build Date: 05/17/15 Sun
                                                                      Local Branch: mybranch10089422
                                                                      Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.22
                                                                      Local Patches: NONE
                                                                      Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030 + 6151be1 +  NOTHING
02-18 13:48:06.053 3752-3788/com.example.ishita.assigntasks I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-18 13:48:06.077 3752-3788/com.example.ishita.assigntasks D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-18 13:48:06.123 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{5fbdde1 V.ED.... ......ID 48,43-403,124} during layout: running second layout pass
02-18 13:48:06.440 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks V/case:msgCount:getInt: 0
02-18 13:48:06.440 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks V/getViewId: 2131493003
02-18 13:48:06.485 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@9dab03c time:19983548
02-18 13:48:10.458 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-18 13:48:10.458 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-18 13:48:10.532 3752-3752/com.example.ishita.assigntasks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.ishita.assigntasks, PID: 3752
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Button.performClick()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.ishita.assigntasks.AddTask$1.onPageScrollStateChanged(AddTask.java:100)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnScrollStateChanged(ViewPager.java:1811)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setScrollState(ViewPager.java:404)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1935)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1961)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
                                                                              at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8742)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4002)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3693)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3750)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5823)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5768)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5936)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
```

Comment: Add the logcat, please

Comment: The text limit doesn't permit. Here is the gist:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.ishita.assigntasks, PID: 3752
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Button.performClick()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.ishita.assigntasks.AddTask$1.onPageScrollStateChanged(AddTask.java:100)
saveTaskBtn

Comment: Added logcat after removing some import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invoked method for a page change(when another page gets selected) in your `OnPageChangeListener` is `onPageSelected`.

Also, calling `getItem` on your `PagerAdapter` **instantiates a new Fragment**. To solve this problem, you'll need to keep a List of your Fragments in your PagerAdapter and create a method to retrieve them.

```
//in PagerAdapter:
private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    fragmentsA = fragments;
    fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        fragmentList.add(Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragmentsA.get(i)););
    }
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position){

    return fragmentList.get(position);
}
```

Comment: I get this on LogCat when I implement this code:

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                             
                                                       at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:442)
                                                       at com.example.ishita.assigntasks.AddTask$SectionsPagerAdapter.<init>(AddTask.java:206)
                                                       at com.example.ishita.assigntasks.AddTask.onCreate(AddTask.java:61)

Comment: What is in lines 206 and 61 in your `AddTask`?

Comment: This is line 206:
`fragmentList.add(Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragmentsA.get(i)););`
This is line 61:
`mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

Comment: I assume `fragmentsA` is empty, when I iterate through it. Can you check this? Maybe you create your `Adapter` before you enter the values in this list?

Comment: Thank you so much, Amy! You saved my life! :) Yes, I had initialized the adapter twice in my activity--once before initializing `List<String> fragments` and once after.


I tried to upvote your answer, but apparently I don't have enough rep to do so. :( Thank you, I learned something new today. :)